# Controller not working in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, controller

I have run zend framework project which is downloaded from live site, in localhost. All are working fine. But in front page, The following errors are shown.

```
There was an error.

Exception information:

Message: Action Helper by name GetEnvPath not found

Stack trace:

#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(293):   Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::_loadHelper('GetEnvPath')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Controller\Action\HelperBroker.php(323): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->getHelper('getEnvPath')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\application\controllers\CustomerController.php(390): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->__call('getEnvPath', Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\application\controllers\CustomerController.php(390): Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker->getEnvPath()
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): CustomerController->accountAction()
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('accountAction')
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\hyperspace_dev\index.php(36): Zend_Application->run()
#10 {main}
Request Parameters:

array (
'controller' => 'customer',
'action' => 'account',
'module' => 'default',
)
```

Front page means After getting login the redirected page
And also controller are not called here

I have searched lot of things.But still now i can't resolved.

If anybody met this same problem, Please save me guys

Answer (score 1):

The actionhelper GetEnvPath cannot be found. Your request and controller are probably right. I would suggest checking if it does exists and if so, if the filename and call have the right case (case sensitivity).

Comment: You mean in application.ini file

Comment: No, in your CustomerController.php on line 390 you're calling the GetEnvPath helper which does not exists.

Comment: in line no 390,i have this line $this->view->envPath = $this->_helper->getEnvPath();

Comment: That's what I'm pointing out: You're calling $this->_helper->getEnvPath(); but this helper cannot be found. Are you sure it exist?

Comment: Actually i'm newbie to zend framework! I have the same coding in the live site, it working fine. but in local only it show the error

Comment: Like RMK said, it's probably a case sensitivity issue if it works in one place and not the other. See if you have a file at `application/controllers/helpers/GetEnvPath.php`. If so, `GetEnvPath.php` is what the filename should be (case sensitive)

Comment: under `application/controllers` directory i have only controllers file in both live and local site. It doesn't have helpers directory. helpers directory is in `\hyperspace_dev\library\My\Action`

Comment: Not only for this controller, No other controllers are also working fine @RMK

Comment: @TimFountain Not only for this controller, No other controllers are also working fine

Comment: Okay, so what's the filename in `\hyperspace_dev\library\My\Action`?

Comment: I have 4 files under this directory 1)Detect.php 2)GetEnvPath.php 3)IsSafari.php 4)UserAgentDetect.php @TimFountain

Answer (score 0):

enable php.ini openssl

it will work ...

:)
Cheers
Neil